# Angular 8 can't import multiple nested components

Tags: angular

I am trying to import component in another component in a page. My structure is:

```
<Parent>
    <listComponent>
        <dataComponent></dataComponent>
    </listComponent>
</parent>
```

The app is able to load

```
<listComponent>
```

but it is throwing error for

```
<dataComponent>
```

Error: Template parse errors:
'dataComponent' is not a known element:
 1. If 'dataComponent' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

Html listComponent

```
<ion-header>
</ion-header>
 <ion-content>
   <mbsc-form [options]="formOption" class="modal-pos">
      <dataComponent>
      </dataComponent>
   </mbsc-form>
</ion-content>
```

Html parent

```
<ion-header>
</ion-header>
 <ion-content>
   <mbsc-form [options]="formOption" class="modal-pos">
      <listComponent>
      </listComponent>
   </mbsc-form>
</ion-content>
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        Parent,
        dataComponent,
        listComponent,
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        Parent,
        dataComponent,
        listComponent,
      ]
})
```

Comment: share the html  code also

Answer (score 2):

Did you try import `dataComponent` in to `listComponent` module?

Or add `dataComponent` to the @NgModule.schemas of component `listComponent` as console message say?

Comment: I have not created listComponent's module file just created it with ionic generate component <component name> and same for <dataComponent> but parent component has module file.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, it was my fault, spelling mistake in the component name. (have two components with almost same names)